# django auto reloading not working when using docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I've researched this topic for days and I could not find the right answer for me.

I have my django app with postgres (postgis) and redis working just fine on the docker, but there is an issue

**Docker does not auto reload after change in file is made**
i need to rebuild whole container to get the smallest of changes. I've tried different configurations but nothing seems to work.
Here is current one
dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11.3-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

ENV REDIS_HOST "redis"
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install netcat gcc postgresql \
    && apt-get clean

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal    

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt ./app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r ./app/requirements.txt

COPY ./entrypoint.sh ./app
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/app/entrypoint.sh"]
COPY . ./app
```

entrypoint

```
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
python manage.py migrate --force
daphne core.asgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0
```

docker compose

```
version: "3.11.3"

services:
  pgdb:
    image: kartoza/postgis
    container_name: postgres_gym
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_files:/home/app/static
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  redis_app:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
        - 6378:6379
  app_django:
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
      - static_files:/usr/src/app/static
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
    links:
      - redis_app

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_files:
```

example of my directory

```
core -- settings.py etc
someapp1 -- first app
someapp2 -- second app
manage.py 
venv
dockerfile
dockercompose
entrypoint.sh
```

I've tried to adding

```
--reload
```

using guicorn instead of daphne in entrypoint.sh

using diffrent configurtions in dockerfile and dockercompose

i know that links is deprecated but even if i remove situation does not change

Comment: Can you use a non-Docker virtual environment for day-to-day development, maybe backed by the Docker containers?  (`docker-compose up -d pgdb redis_app`, and point your application config to `localhost` and the first `ports:` number for the two components.)  It looks like your Dockerfile generally installs the application code into `/app/app` but the bind mount hides all of `/app` with host content, and the mismatched paths could be a problem.

Comment: what path shoudl I change?